# how to createViewer in Cesium Angular

Tags: angular, cesiumjs

New to Cesium, trying to use angular-cesium in my Angular project. I'm having trouble creating a new view with creatViewer(). I get the map element, then attempt to create the viewer with it. but it is giving me an error pictured below.

maybe I'm not getting the right element? or maybe it's not the right HTMLElement type.
as a side note, can I do all this in ngOnInit?

component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation, AfterViewInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { CesiumService } from 'angular-cesium/src/services/cesium/cesium.service';
import { ViewerFactory } from 'angular-cesium/src/services/viewer-factory/viewer-factory.service'

@Component({
    selector: 'app-globe',
    templateUrl: './globe.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./globe.component.css'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class GlobeComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
    cesiumViewer;
    cesiumScene;
    cesiumCanvas;
    mapElement;
    acceptAllURL = 'http://65.102.85.13:8080/rest/kml/accept/all';

    constructor(private cesiumService: CesiumService,
                private viewerFactory: ViewerFactory) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        // this.loadCesium();
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.loadCesium();
    }

    loadCesium() {
        this.mapElement = window.document.getElementsByClassName('cesium-viewer');
        console.log(this.mapElement)
        this.cesiumViewer = this.viewerFactory.createViewer(this.mapElement)
        // this.cesiumCanvas = this.cesiumService.getCanvas();
        // this.cesiumScene = this.cesiumService.getScene();

        console.log(this.cesiumViewer)

        // const options = {
        //     camera : this.cesiumScene,
        //     canvas : this.cesiumCanvas,
        //     proxy : new Cesium.DefaultProxy('/proxy/')
        // };

        // const dataSourceAcceptAll = new Cesium.KmlDataSource(options);
        // dataSourceAcceptAll.load(this.acceptAllURL, options);
    }
}
```

error: [image: error log]

Comment: Try changing `getElementsByClassName('cesium-viewer')` to `querySelector('.cesium-viewer')`

Comment: `createViewer` method expects `HtmlElement` but you pass `HtmlCollection` to it

Comment: changed it to querySelector, still same error

Comment: What is the output of console.log?

Comment: same exact thing as the image above

Comment: Array? `document.querySelector('.cesium-viewer')` should return one element